# ZMQ_CONFLATE socket option cause no messages to be received

Tags: c++, zeromq

I'm trying to find the cause of why enabling the ZMQ_CONFLATE option causes no messages to be received.

I recreated this minimal testcase (my application uses XPUB/XSUB proxy, however, it seems this does not change the outcome of this test):

```
#include <atomic>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <zmq.hpp>

#define USE_PROXY

std::atomic<bool> stop{false};

void pub_thread(zmq::context_t &context)
{
    zmq::socket_t pub(context, zmq::socket_type::pub);
#ifdef USE_PROXY
    pub.connect("tcp://localhost:38922");
#else
    pub.bind("tcp://*:38923");
#endif
    long i = 0;
    for(;;)
    {
        if(stop) break;
        std::string m = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);
        zmq::message_t hdr(6);
        memcpy(hdr.data(), "topic1", 6);
        zmq::message_t msg(m.size());
        memcpy(msg.data(), m.data(), m.size());
        std::cout << "send: " << m << std::endl;
        if(!pub.send(hdr, ZMQ_SNDMORE) || !pub.send(msg))
            std::cout << "send error" << std::endl;
        i++;
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds{20});
    }
}

void sub_thread(zmq::context_t &context)
{
    zmq::socket_t sub(context, zmq::socket_type::sub);
    const int v_true = 1;
    sub.setsockopt(ZMQ_CONFLATE, &v_true, sizeof(v_true));
#ifdef USE_PROXY
    sub.connect("tcp://localhost:38921");
#else
    sub.connect("tcp://localhost:38923");
#endif
    sub.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "topic1", 6);
    for(;;)
    {
        if(stop) break;
        zmq::message_t hdr, msg;
        if(!sub.recv(&hdr) || !hdr.more() || !sub.recv(&msg))
            std::cout << "recv error" << std::endl;
        std::string m(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(msg.data()), msg.size());
        std::cout << "                recv: " << m << std::endl;
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds{250});
    }
}

void proxy_thread(zmq::context_t &context)
{
#ifdef USE_PROXY
    zmq::socket_t xpub(context, zmq::socket_type::xpub);
    xpub.bind("tcp://*:38921");
    zmq::socket_t xsub(context, zmq::socket_type::xsub);
    xsub.bind("tcp://*:38922");
    std::cout << "starting xpub/xsub proxy" << std::endl;
    zmq::proxy(xpub, xsub, nullptr);
    std::cout << "xpub/xsub proxy terminated" << std::endl;
#endif
}

void timeout_thread()
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{4});
    stop = true;
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{1});
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    boost::thread t0(&timeout_thread);
    boost::thread t1(&proxy_thread, boost::ref(context));
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{1});
    boost::thread t2(&sub_thread, boost::ref(context));
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{1});
    boost::thread t3(&pub_thread, boost::ref(context));
    t0.join();
}
```

Quick description: we have 4 threads:

- pub thread: writes the value of an increasing counter every 20ms to a PUB socket
- sub thread: reads the value from the SUB socket every 250ms (messages are supposed to queue up, but due to the conflate option, should be discarded except the most recent)
- proxy thread: runs the XPUB/XSUBN proxy (if USE_PROXY is defined)
- timeout thread: stop everything after 4 seconds

The output I observe is the following:

```
starting xpub/xsub proxy
send: 0
send: 1
send: 2
send: 3
send: 4
send: 5
send: 6
send: 7
send: 8
send: 9
send: 10
send: 11
send: 12
send: 13
send: 14
send: 15
send: 16
send: 17
send: 18
send: 19
send: 20
send: 21
send: 22
send: 23
send: 24
send: 25
send: 26
send: 27
send: 28
send: 29
send: 30
send: 31
send: 32
send: 33
send: 34
send: 35
send: 36
send: 37
send: 38
send: 39
send: 40
send: 41
send: 42
send: 43
send: 44
send: 45
send: 46
send: 47
send: 48
send: 49
send: 50
send: 51
send: 52
send: 53
send: 54
send: 55
send: 56
send: 57
send: 58
send: 59
send: 60
send: 61
send: 62
send: 63
send: 64
send: 65
send: 66
send: 67
send: 68
send: 69
send: 70
send: 71
send: 72
send: 73
send: 74
send: 75
send: 76
send: 77
send: 78
send: 79
send: 80
send: 81
send: 82
send: 83
send: 84
send: 85
send: 86
send: 87
```

i.e. no message is ever received.

The expected output should be something like this:

```
starting xpub/xsub proxy
send: 0
send: 1
                recv: 1
send: 2
send: 3
send: 4
send: 5
send: 6
send: 7
send: 8
send: 9
send: 10
send: 11
                recv: 11
send: 12
send: 13
send: 14
send: 15
send: 16
send: 17
send: 18
send: 19
send: 20
send: 21
send: 22
                recv: 21
send: 23
send: 24
send: 25
send: 26
send: 27
send: 28
send: 29
send: 30
send: 31
send: 32
send: 33
send: 34
                recv: 33
send: 35
send: 36
send: 37
send: 38
send: 39
send: 40
send: 41
send: 42
send: 43
send: 44
send: 45
                recv: 45
send: 46
send: 47
send: 48
send: 49
send: 50
send: 51
send: 52
send: 53
send: 54
send: 55
send: 56
                recv: 55
send: 57
send: 58
send: 59
send: 60
send: 61
send: 62
send: 63
send: 64
send: 65
send: 66
send: 67
                recv: 66
send: 68
send: 69
send: 70
send: 71
send: 72
send: 73
send: 74
send: 75
send: 76
send: 77
send: 78
                recv: 77
send: 79
send: 80
send: 81
send: 82
send: 83
send: 84
send: 85
send: 86
send: 87
```

I tried also moving `sub.setsockopt(ZMQ_CONFLATE,...` after `sub.connect(...` but in that case it has no effect, the same effect as removing the ZMQ_CONFLATE line:

```
starting xpub/xsub proxy
send: 0
send: 1
                recv: 1
send: 2
send: 3
send: 4
send: 5
send: 6
send: 7
send: 8
send: 9
send: 10
send: 11
                recv: 2
send: 12
send: 13
send: 14
send: 15
send: 16
send: 17
send: 18
send: 19
send: 20
send: 21
send: 22
                recv: 3
send: 23
send: 24
send: 25
send: 26
send: 27
send: 28
send: 29
send: 30
send: 31
send: 32
send: 33
send: 34
                recv: 4
send: 35
send: 36
send: 37
send: 38
send: 39
send: 40
send: 41
send: 42
send: 43
send: 44
send: 45
                recv: 5
send: 46
send: 47
send: 48
send: 49
send: 50
send: 51
send: 52
send: 53
send: 54
send: 55
send: 56
                recv: 6
send: 57
send: 58
send: 59
send: 60
send: 61
send: 62
send: 63
send: 64
send: 65
send: 66
send: 67
                recv: 7
send: 68
send: 69
send: 70
send: 71
send: 72
send: 73
send: 74
send: 75
send: 76
send: 77
send: 78
                recv: 8
send: 79
send: 80
send: 81
send: 82
send: 83
send: 84
send: 85
send: 86
send: 87
```

ZMQ version: 4.2.5

Comment: Can you put a trace to see when you call send with SNDMORE flag and when you  call send without the flag ? A possibility is that you are never calling send without the flag (I read your code in diagonal so far I could be wrong)

Comment: `pub.send(hdr, ZMQ_SNDMORE)` should [send](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/master/zmq.hpp#L692) with `SNDMORE` flag. when the second argument is omitted, it defaults to *not* using the `SNDMORE` flag. I'll check if [`cppzmq`](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq) has some sort of bug like that, but I doubt so.

Comment: when [`pub.send(hdr, ZMQ_SNDMORE)`](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/master/zmq.hpp#L692) returns true (successful send), `!pub.send(hdr, ZMQ_SNDMORE)` is false, so the second branch of the if (`||`) is executed, so it does not happen the "short-circuit" evaluation

Comment: http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-msg-send "The zmq_msg_send() function shall return number of bytes in the message if successful. Otherwise it shall return -1 and set errno to one of the values defined below." By the way, [`zmq::socket_t::send(message_t &msg_, int flags_)`](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/master/zmq.hpp#L692-L700) returns a `bool`

Comment: Does it work without the conflate ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using multipart messages which are not compatible with `ZMQ_CONFLATE`

> ZMQ_CONFLATE: Keep only last message If set, a socket shall keep only
>   one message in its inbound/outbound queue, this message being the last
>   message received/the last message to be sent. Ignores ZMQ_RECVHWM and
>   ZMQ_SENDHWM options. Does not supports multi-part messages, in
>   particular, only one part of it is kept in the socket internal queue.

If you change the code to send **one message part** (the integer) and subscribe to all `sub.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);` the code produces the results you expected.

Answer (score 0):

In you subscribe socket, try setting the `ZMQ_CONFLATE` prior to connecting.

From the docs:

http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-setsockopt

> Caution: All options, with the exception of ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE, ZMQ_LINGER, ZMQ_ROUTER_HANDOVER, ZMQ_ROUTER_MANDATORY, ZMQ_PROBE_ROUTER, ZMQ_XPUB_VERBOSE, ZMQ_XPUB_VERBOSER, ZMQ_REQ_CORRELATE, ZMQ_REQ_RELAXED, ZMQ_SNDHWM and ZMQ_RCVHWM, only take effect for subsequent socket bind/connects.

Good example code though, was nice to see your expected outcome.

Comment: As I told in my question (the very last sentence), if I set the ZMQ_CONFLATE in the SUB socket prior to connecting, no messages are received.

Comment: Well if that's the case then your question should be why does `ZMQ_CONFLATE` causes no messages to be received.  Putting the `ZMQ_CONFLATE` after the connect is wrong and never going to work.

Comment: Which version of `libzmq` are you using?

Comment: 4.2.5 (I updated my question with these informations, we can remove some of the no longer needed comments)